# Strange linking error while compiling mlpack

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++, mlpack

mlpack was perfectly compiling on my systems a few days back. I don't know what I did that's causing the following strange linking error:

```
[ 37%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libmlpack.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib/libiberty.a(cplus-dem.o): warning: relocation against `libiberty_demanglers' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib/libiberty.a(cp-demangle.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `cplus_demangle_builtin_types' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/build.make:1040: lib/libmlpack.so.3.4] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2106: src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

I tried adding the -fPIC flag to the cmake file but it still gives the same error

Comment: The error is about that `/usr/lib/libiberty.a` library should be built with `-fPIC`. Adding this
 flag when compile mlpack library doesn't resolve the problem. You need to rebuild `libiberty.a` library instead (or find shared version of that library).

Comment: How do I rebuild the libiberty.a library? I found this (http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sunfreeware/pub/freeware/forsunsites/libiberty.html) online but the download link seems broken